# Can't make AJAX call to local webserver from HTML5 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to make a simple AJAX request from an HTML5 app to a local webserver. 
However, because the client code was not served from the webserver, I'm getting the 
"Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error.

I've tried everything described in the following post, but still doesn't work: [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

If I post my server code on an Internet-hosted server, the client app works.
But I'd like it to work with my local MAMP server which is running on the same laptop.

1) On the local webserver, I added the following to my PHP controller:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

2) Here's my HTML5 client app. JSONP should not been needed since the server supports CORS.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <base href='http://192.168.15.12/'></base> <!-- local MAMP server -->     
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#leadButton').click(function(){

                    $.getJSON(
                        'get/leaderboard',
                        function(data){
                            var leader;

                            leader = "<div> The top leader is from local webserver is: " +  data[0].name + "</div>";
                            $('#leaderboard').append(leader);
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    );     
                });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="leaderboard">Leaderboard
        <button id="leadButton">Get Leaderboard</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

3) When I call the client app (file:///Users/John/Desktop/index.html) from Chrome, and click on the leadButton" button, here are the resulting request/response headers:

```
Request URL:http://192.168.15.12/get/leaderboard
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:403 Forbidden

Request Headers
Access-Control-Request-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Accept
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Origin:null

Response Headers
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:227
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Thu, 03 Nov 2011 19:03:27 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache
```

What am I missing?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem:

The request to the local webserver (192.168.15.12) requires the full URL to specified in the $.getJSON request: "http://192.168.15.12/get/leaderboard"

The "base" tag did not prepend "http://192.168.15.12/" to the URL in the jQuery call.

I also needed to add the following Apache config to my .htaccess file to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) (doing this in PHP did not work reliably):

```
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

Answer (score 0):

accesing:

```
file:///Users/John/Desktop/index.html
```

won't work. Because file:/// is not the same as localhost.

You need to access http://192.168.15.12/index.html for this to work

Comment: But I'm building a client app; it is not served up from a website, so your suggestion wouldn't work.  "file:///Users/John/Desktop/index.html" works if my server code is deployed on an Internet server (e.g. www.myexternalserver.com), but not on my local webserver (192.168.15.12).